# VS 2019 ASP.Net Core + React Template -- How do you display the NavbarToggler?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Steps to recreate the issue:

1. Open Visual Studio 2019
2. Select *Create a New Project...*.
3. Select the ASP.Net Core Application with React and Redux template, and select where to save your project.
4. Select your .Net Core version (in my case, it's .NET Core 3.1 (LTS)
5. Finish the template setup.
6. Hit F5 to build and run once the solution loads.

The fresh application works just fine, however if you open up the `..\ClientApp\src\components\NavMenu.tsx` file, you will see that there is a reference to the `NavbarToggler` react component.  We see the `NavItem` list of links render to the navbar on the page when the demo loads, but the toggler does not display or work.

**How can I display the NavbarToggler?**

Further tests have revealed that the `Navbar` Bootstrap components are not working.  There's a reasonable chance that other Bootstrap components aren't working either.

I have a new project I need to work on, and I need these tools.  I can search for other, third party component libraries but it's a shame that what's referenced within the demos would work for my companies needs, however, the implementation in the default, React template does not work.  I'd like to stick with Bootstrap, so a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind adding the .net core version u use?

Comment: @TheTanic I added it, but I'm not sure why the .Net Core version would affect the UI.  Technically, this is strictly a UI project and node should be able to build and serve the project outside of Visual Studio.  This sample app doesn't make server calls directly from the home page.  Regardless, I've provided my .Net Core version which is 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the HTML code generated by React, you'll notice that a <button> element is generated for the `<NavbarToggler>` with the following CSS style:

[image]

This means that the `<NavbarToggler>` is meant for mobile use, and indeed if you resize your browser window below 576px in width the button appears:

[image]

The purpose of the `<NavbarToggler>` is to hide the contents of the `<Navbar>`, and add a button to expand the `<Navbar>`. So the `<NavbarToggler>` in the React template project works as expected. If you don't want that behavior, you will have to either add different classes to the `<Navbar>` (see below) or modify the Bootstrap CSS although I wouldn't recommend this.

You can read more about how to control the `<NavbarToggler>` in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors):

> Navbars can utilize .navbar-toggler, .navbar-collapse, and .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} classes to change when their content collapses behind a button. In combination with other utilities, you can easily choose when to show or hide particular elements.

> For navbars that never collapse, add the .navbar-expand class on the navbar. For navbars that always collapse, don’t add any .navbar-expand class.

If you want to show the `<NavbarToggler>` all the time, remove the `navbar-expand-sm` class from the `<Navbar>` and the `d-sm-inline-flex` class from the `<Collapse>`.

Comment: Ok, this answer is close.  I do see what you are showing.  However, in creating my own react app with the CRA app, and installing ReactStrap, this is not default behavior.  I also do not see any of the code in the default NavMenu.js code, nor can I spot it in the css provided for the application.  Can you figure out how to properly turn this off.  Even though I can tell you're on the right path, this doesn't seem to be documented in he sample and it is a bit confusing.  I tried to add other samples of the Collapse area, and even those would not work.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the easiest way to fix this is to remove all of the bootstrap CSS from the related components.  I am going to give you the Bounty, but please update your answer to reflect this change, since it is part of what I requested as part of the answer--it's the how to fix this part of the question, not just the need for understanding why this is happening?

Comment: @RLH It's still not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but I hope the edited answer is better.

Comment: I want the toggle area to work, regardless of the size state of the window.  This functionality is disabled by additional CSS.  I want the project to have a collapsable menu, regardless of if the size of the browser window, or if it's on a mobile device.

Comment: @RLH then the last paragraph in the answer is what you need.

Comment: Ok, Answer awarded.  Thank you.